# Как ограничить сотрудникам доступ к развлекательным сайтам

Tags: администрирование

Как ограничить сотрудникам доступ к развлекательным сайтам?
15 человек в организации, домена нет, есть основной пк на нём Debian+samba, основной роутер TL-WR740N
В данный момент у всех свободный доступ в интернет.
Нужно ограничить доступы на отдельно некоторым людям, чтобы не заходили на различные сайты, даже в новостные

Comment: Поставить на ваш "основной пк", например, squid, настроить его, завернуть всех ваших юзеров на этот прокси, а на прокси запрещать сайты, которые необходимо запретить.

Comment: а если сайтов много? в ручную добавлять? в таком случает что делают?

Comment: Для конторы из 15-ти человек вручную добавляют. Для конторы из 1500+ можно купить нечто наподобие https://www.barracuda.com/products/websecuritygateway

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Ваш роутер TL-WR740N имеет встроенный для этого механизм. 
В меню Access Control надо настроить:

1. Shedule - время действия запрета (например с 9 до 17 по будним дням)
2. Target - то, что нельзя (перечень сайтов на которые нельзя ходить)
3. Hosts - кому нельзя ( перечень компьютеров на которые будет действовать правило)
4. Rule - собственно правила. Включите галку "Enable Internet Access Control", выберите "Deny the packets specified..." нажмите кнопку "Add new" и создайте правило. Придумайте название для правила и выберите из списков ниже уже созданные группы "кому нельзя", "куда нельзя" и "когда нельзя".

Comment: Большое спасибо за развёрнутый ответ, а можно на всегда заблочить интернет полностью?

Comment: Есть еще настройка "Parental Control" в роутере - там настраивается кому, куда и когда можно, а все остальное нельзя. 
:) если всем и навсегда не надо видеть интернет, то можете просто прописать неправильный ip адрес в dhcp и все у кого не статически прописанные настройки не смогут найти сайт по имени. или наоборот - руками прописать адрес на компьютере тем, кому не нужен интернет. Но это легко обойти, если владеть темой.

Comment: Админских прав нет, я думаю просто отключить сетку, или в роутере можно по мак адресу заблокировать инет?

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно на этом роутере открыть пользователю доступ только к некоторым сайтам то надо использовать меню "Parental control"

1. поставить галочку enable
2. нажать кнопку "add new..."
3. Заполнить форму начиная со второй строки
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]